# Video/Audio Recording on Website service/Save to server

Tags: c#, php, .net, silverlight, flash

I am developing (well, trying to anyway) a service where a member can record themselves on our website using their webcam. We need to be able to record that entire webcam session they had on our website for judges to determine whether they've cheated or not (it's a competition-based service).

But, I can find no documentation, articles or even a sign that this is possible (other than knowing I've seen it in use many times). And I'm not sure what kind of hosting would be most appropriate for this type of service, and what steps would be required for me to get started on this.

I'd really appreciate any help at all.

Do you know of any links/tuts/articles/documentation, types of hosting required and/or samples that may be floating around? Maybe even existing open source solutions?

I really have searched high and low for.. *something* to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The most common solution is using the Flash player in the browser to stream audio and video content to Flash Media Server(FMS), Wowza or Red5 on the server side. Server side applications for FMS are coded in a version of Actionscript, while Wowza and Red5 use Java.

More information  and tutorials can be found here:

- http://www.flashcomguru.com/
- http://fmsguru.com
- http://www.red5.org/
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver.html

Third party hosting is also available via companies like Influxis:

- http://www.influxis.com/

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin C, I appreciate it. I'll have a look at those links now.